# MX record configuration for hosted email?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, web-hosting

I am helping a friend with his website, and am having a problem with his webmail configuration, which I suspect is due to a misconfigured MX record.

His domain is registered and hosted by hostmonster, they have a webmail option.

A record:

```
Host    Points To       TTL

webmail 12.345.789.101  14400
```

CNAME:

```
mail    webmail.d.com   14400
```

MX Record:

```
0   @   mail.d.com  14400
```

I've created an email account on hostmonster, test@d.com: however, when I sent an email to this account, it *appears* to be routing to /dev/null. I know that it's not actually, but am unsure of the steps I can take to track this down?

I've tried using dig, but am unsure where to start. How can I track down where this email is being routed to?

Answer (score 0):

use [mxtoolbox.com](http://mxtoolbox.com)

to track routing issues. if it resolves to the ip address then it's going to be problem with the hosting provider.

Why not just setup a free google apps account and use that instead.